# Disable selection of parent rows in a QTreeWidget

Tags: python, selection, pyside, qtreewidget

I populate nested lists in a QTreeWidget, and I need to disable the selection of parent rows.

The code is:

```
def fillTree(self):
    '''
    Fill UI with list of parts
    '''
    roots = ['APLE', 'ORANGE', 'MANGO']
    childs = ['body', 'seed', 'stern']
    parent = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
    for root in roots:
        widgetTrim = QTreeWidgetItem()
        widgetTrim.setText(0, root)
        parent.addChild(widgetTrim)
        for child in childs:
            widgetPart = QTreeWidgetItem()
            widgetPart.setText(0, child)
            widgetTrim.addChild(widgetPart)
```

[image]

I need to avoid selection of the "fruit" items.

Comment: QTreeView or QTreeWidget? **QTreeWidgetItem**

Comment: Main widget - QTreeWidget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove `Qt.ItemIsSelectable` from the [item-flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum):

```
widgetTrim = QTreeWidgetItem()
widgetTrim.setFlags(widgetTrim.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
```

The flags are an OR'd together combination `ItemFlag` values. So a [bitwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) AND NOT operation is used to remove the `ItemIsSelectable` from the existing combination of flags.

Comment: @kiryha. It's bitwise AND NOT. The flags are OR'd together, so it takes all the current flags, but without the selectable flag.